# Kernel problem while initializing Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, jupyter-lab

I have installed Anaconda and along with it I tried working with Jupyter notebook but can't seem to have kernel while opening a notebook python file. In the below [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgEEQ.jpg) (line 2) it can be seen that notebook is starting with 2 kernels.

[image: Fig 1: Command prompt output. (On the second line we can see 2 kernels found)]

Here in the below [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDZGE.jpg) shown kernels are 4 (dropdown shown in top right).
[image: Fig 2: Kernels shown in the Jupyter notebook.]

After opening the file in Python 3 kernel, shown kernels in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34yaP.jpg) is not showing any (top right corner and in the dropdown menu).
[image: Fig 3: Kernels shown in the file opened]

I have tried method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459493/jupyter-lab-and-notebook-problem-kernel-error), but couldn't do much as path seems to be correct as per python.exe location in an environment. I have tried to add kernel as well mentioned in this [link](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000019210), but didn't help in my case. I have also tried to make another environment and then freshly install python and jupyter as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318374/anaconda-jupyter-notebooks-kernel-problems), but no luck there either. Couldn't use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59710188/problems-with-jupyter-python-kernel) either as already tried reinstalling and do not want to do it again because with too much complications I have installed OpenCV (**:P**).

So, basically I am stuck on how to operate the python kernel in Jupyter notebook/lab ?